# Constructor of worker it doen't called?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I try to implement a timer using Work Manager.

"Timer button was hit" is appear in logcat, but nothing comes from worker. What I do wrong?

This is my ViewModel class:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    private final WorkManager workManager;

    public MainViewModel(WorkManager workManager) {
        this.workManager = workManager;
    }

    public void count() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Timer button was hit!");

        OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MainWorker.class).build();
        workManager.beginUniqueWork("count-work", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, request).enqueue();
    }
}
```

This is my worker. Nothing appear in logcat from here. I don't know why.

```
public class MainWorker extends Worker {


    public MainWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        Log.d(MainViewModel.LOG_TAG, "Created");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(MainViewModel.LOG_TAG, "Work start");
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel(WorkManager.getInstance(this));
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setMainViewModel(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, I called "prune" function, then it works

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels are not initialized the way you did. If you have to pass something to ViewModel constructor, you should probably consider using `ViewModelProvider.Factory()`.

You can make your own ViewModelProvider.Factory()

Refer this, [https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f#:~:text=And%20it%20is%20because%20you,it%20will%20create%20your%20ViewModel](https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f#:%7E:text=And%20it%20is%20because%20you,it%20will%20create%20your%20ViewModel).